# Set the color of a link that is loaded from the jQuery '.load()' method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, getelementbyid

In my index.html file I have the following code:

```
<div id="navbar"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/navigation.css">');
        $("#navbar").load("scripts/navigationbar.html");
    });
</script>
```

and the navigationbar.html file is:

```
<nav>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li><a id="nav-page-1" href="page1.html">Page 1</a></li>
            <li><a id="nav-page-2" href="page2.html">Page 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

The markup and stylesheets load and show correctly, but what I wanted to do was copy and paste the jQuery code in every page. However, the difference would be that on page one the color or "Page 1" should be different than the other links on the bar, and on page two the color of "Page 2" should be a different color, etc. How could I achieve this with the above code?

I tried:

```
document.getElementById("nav-page-1").color = "#ff0000";
```

But that didn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Just a side comment: why are you using jQuery/javascript to append the stylesheet? Can you not just add the link code directly in the page html? I realize the navigation bar is on every page, so you can edit it once and inject it dynamically, but css link tags do that for you.

Comment: I just did that so I could copy-paste the nav bar code into every page without having to copy the link into the head tag too. The stylesheet navigation.css is only used for the navbar, so I didn't think it needed to be there until the navbar was used. Is it a bad idea to append a stylesheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to select the element in a callback after the HTML has been added.

```
$("#navbar").load("scripts/navigationbar.html", function () {
  document.getElementById("nav-page-1").style.color = "#ff0000";
});
```

Based on the code you provided, you were probably trying to select the element before it existed. The `.load()` method is asynchronous, so that logic should be added in a callback so that it is fired when the event completes. As a side note, you also need to access the `color` property on the `style` object (i.e., `element.style.color` rather than `element.color`).

Comment: This looks nicer `$('#nav-page-1').css('color', '#ff0000');`

Answer (score 1):

DOMElement doesn't have a color property, you set the color by setting the color of the style property.

`document.getElementById("nav-page-1").style.color = "#ff0000";`